# Asp Update Panel - Details View Updates Underlying GridView doesn't

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dataview

I have an Asp.net gridview on a page, when a buttonfield is clicked (instead of select) it opens a popup form (my popup not asp's) which contains the detail of the gridview row displayed in an editable DetailsView. (This approach has been used because the grid contains 20 wideish columns and it is easier to edit / update in the detailsView format) The DetailsView takes any amendmends and writes them back to the table, fine, but the underlying Gridview is never visually updated unless of course the page is completely reloaded (I tried to use the Windows.reload function but I get the annoying winddows is trying to reopen etc, error, so that is useless). I am trying to discover the best way to get the gridview to refresh it's data. I have placed via a Me.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType() eyc, an alert box to communicate when the 'update steps' of the detailsview fires so I could interject a gridview.ReBind()  but because the detailsview is held within the update panel the, for example, Protected Sub DetailsView2_ItemUpdated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs) Handles DetailsView2.ItemUpdated functions, and the roqwupdatind and so one, do not appear to fire. (they must do of course else the table would not be updating. MY problem is how do I 'communicate with update events within the panel contained detailsviews so that I can cause a reBind to occur on the main gridview. Any Ideas would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

Detail view have an event called

```
protected void dvEbook_ItemUpdated(object sender, DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl,false);
        }
```

where dvEbook is my detail view.

It will call a same page.

I hope it will work for you.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Prateek. Thank you for your response. I will give that a try, I suspect that is just what I'm seeking, so thanks again. Temporarily I disable the panel because I 'had to move on' but I will use this on the next project / update panel trial. Good luck