# GridView contents don’t update when underlying data changes

Tags: asp.net, gridview

So I have an ASP.NET page with two controls:

- a `GridView` which displays rows from a `SqlDataSource`, and in which the user can select a row;
- a `DetailsView` in which the user can see *and edit* the values of the selected row.

The `DetailsView` can update the underlying data, but even though the page reloads, the `GridView` still displays the old data until I *manually* reload the page in the browser.

How do I ensure that the `GridView` displays the correct data after the update in the `DetailsView`?

P.S. It may be important to note that [due to reasons outlined in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080971/), I had to use a custom `OnItemUpdating` event with the `DetailsView`. This event performs the SQL update command (successfully), sets the `DetailsView` back to ReadOnly mode (out of Edit mode) and then cancels the event (`e.Cancel = true`). If this event canceling also somehow cancels the `GridView` updating, how do I manually tell it to update itself?

P.P.S.: I discovered [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837439), but the answer doesn’t work: it resets the entire page back to pristine state, which means the `GridView` loses its selected row and the `DetailsView` disappears. I don’t want that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on page load:

```
YourGridViewID.DataBind()
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I added it to the end of the `DataView`’s `OnItemUpdating` handler instead of `Page_Load()` though.

Answer (score 0):

If your `OnItemUpdating` event generates postback

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        GridView.DataBind();//rebinding it with considering changes DetailView
    }
}
```

If it doesn't work let me know.